# Is there a way to use Google Drive Picker in an iOS app?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-workspace

Currently, I suddenly received a unilateral notification from Google Drive Product to change the drive.readonly range to drive.file and a short transition time.

Our app has been providing two functions in the iOS app for almost 3-4 years: browsing and downloading Google Drive files.

Rather than imposing restrictions on new projects, there is an app that is being serviced in an existing project, and it is very embarrassing to suddenly be told not to use the feature.

The drive.file scope cannot retrieve a list of all files on the drive.

We are considering whether it is possible to use Google Drive Picker in JavaScript.
(There are very few ways to do this.)

If you use a JavaScript picker, you must create an “API Key” and create a new “OAuth 2.0 Client ID” as “Web Client”.
(Previously, one “OAuth 2.0 Client ID” was created for iOS apps.)

1. I would like to know how to launch Google Drive Picker using webview in iOS/Swift environment.
2. I wonder if there is a way to download the selected file to the app in iOS native code when the user selects a file through a webview or SafariController.

Comment: I'm in the same situation as you but launching a web view inside of the app and creating a Javascript bridge sounds like a hack. If Google wants us to migrate to using drive.file they should provide a way to natively launch a picker from iOS which it does not look like it exists.

Comment: @Enrique R. Thank you for answer. Currently, Google does not provide Google Drive Picker for iOS (or Android) only. Or maybe I just don't know.

Comment: Are you having any luck with this? I've made a prototype to use the Google Drive Picker inside of an iOS app but looks terrible and is not responsive. The experience of using the picker inside of a native app is simply not good. Let me know if you have figured something out.

Comment: I'm in the same boat. I've been trying to get the use of the restricted "drive" scope re-verified (which I've been using since 2016). Now Google wants me to complete a CASA Tier 3 security assessment by an authorized lab which "can take up to 6 weeks depending on how engaged and responsive you are in the whole process". Since it would take ~60 hours of my time, is required annually and would cost a lot of money, this isn't going to be feasible for me as an indie app developer.

Did any of you find a solution on how to use the narrower drive.file scope in an iOS app?

Comment: Currently, CASA certification is in progress for apps included in Google Drive. Currently, it seems that this is the only way to use Google Drive. It would be nice if Google made a Drive Picker for iOS, but we're disappointed that Google still doesn't seem to have any ideas about it.